# Redirect entire folder to maintenance page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I´m trying to redirect an entire folder which is in domain.com/folder/templates1/, to a maintenance .html page, however I´m getting into a redirect loop with the next code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/templates1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /mypage.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone check this and let me know how could I avoid that loop?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC] 
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Which URL did you try for testing? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: The thing here is that I have 2 child folders coming from /folder/, so I have folder/templates1/ and folder/templates2/, and I want to redirect just entire /templates1/ files and subfolders to /mypage.html which is in root, .. How do I get that?

Comment: ok see updated code, this should be placed in `/folder/.htaccess` Wha t is your full URL for `folder/templates1/`?

Comment: Its not working, I cannot provide the url here, isnt there any way to make this work?

Comment: You cannot provide a URL? You can't tell filesystem location of .htaccess either? And you want help? btw I wat not asking your real domain. Replace that with `example.com`

Comment: its example.com/folder/templates1/, I have a .htaccess in root, and I placed the updated .htaccess you told into the /folder/ folder, but still not redirecting to example.com/mypage.html

Comment: Try updated code one more time. Also are you .htaccess is enabled for you?

Comment: Yes, htaccess is enabled, not working anyway... dont know what else to try

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of this `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Not generating any error, some images just dissappear when code is placed, so I guess that is doing some kind of effect, but not redirecting to the html page.

Comment: Did you place some random text in this .htaccess?

Comment: Ok, is there any other way that I can redirect one of 2 sites to example.com/mypage.html, both sharing /folder/ but with different subfolders? site1: folder/templates1/ - site2/folder/templates2/, and I just want to redirect site1 to mypage.html.. ? How to get that? Thank you for your help

Comment: it redirects css but not working correctly dont know why, I will try another solution, thanks for your time

Comment: Can you define `not working correctly`. Rule is most simple now which redirects **everything** in the given directory. So if it works for one file it will work for others also.

Comment: the only code that I tried and worked was this one: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mypage.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /mypage.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule> However this works for all domains, and what I need is that one of the domains doesnt follow this rule

Comment: see updated rule above and replace `example.com` wit your actual domain name.

Comment: Man, wow! Works like charm, one domain shows and the other don´t, that´s what I was looking for, really nice job, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/templates1 [NC]
RewriteRule . /mypage.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Should do it. It should send *any* request starting with `/folder/templates1` to /mypage.html, with a 302 (**temporary** redirect) status. What were you trying to do with the image files? Do you want them exempted? That wasn't in your specification, but can be added with one line:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
```

Of course, you're on a server (Apache?) that recognizes .htaccess, and the mod_rewrite is enabled.